# Android studio layout bug

Tags: android-studio

Hello im trying to put a TextView in my app, but when i drag it this happens. Ive added the style and layout xmls

Please forgive me if there is any newbie errors, im kinda new to this

[image]

My theme.xml file:

```kotlin
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />

    <style name="AppBgTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launcher_bg</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" parent="@style/Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />
    <style name="Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" parent="@style/Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />
</resources>
```

layout xml:

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@id/activity_main"
    android:padding="6.0dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView111"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#00AAFF"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.442" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: well we need the layout xml to debug this, the style xml has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: ive edited the post with the layout xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added a + next to id in `@id/activity_main` which indicates that this id isn't identified yet and it's the first time to mention.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:padding="6.0dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView111"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#00AAFF"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.442" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

if that doesn't solve your problem, check your `build.gradle(Module:app)` may be you didn't add the androidx constraint layout dependency and that's why your layout doesn't recognize it.

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
...
}
```

Comment: Still didnt fixed it, even after removing the id

Comment: if you hovered your mouse cursor on the red text what does it say ? because everything works naturally in my app.

Comment: problem is, there is no red text on the layout

Comment: try to build the project then share what error do you get after building, does it build naturally without any errors but still shows like the design in the actual app? sometimes the problem that the design only renders a cached layout.

Comment: it fixed it by iteself after building, thanks!